# Page showing blank whitespace before loading

Tags: javascript, php, pageload

I have the following code for a website that I'm working on.  It is for business use.  The website is actually in PHP and the file is index.php as it exists on the server.  You may see the website at:  www.tradingcharts.ca.  So far the website works perfectly in terms of functionality. There's still some functions to add such as saving form data to disk and data validation.

My problem is that there's a noticeable delay for whenever the end-user loads the website.  This delay also occurs when the end-user hits the submit button on the form to open an account or to log in an account.  The delay lasts for about a half a second where the screen turns to a blank white-space before the content is rendered.  The thing is though, this phenomenon doesn't occur when I have the website loaded on my personal computer where I'm using IIS; it only occurs when its uploaded to the off-site server.  I am open to suggestions as to how to correct this problem.  Please feel free to review the source code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>









</head>
<body>




<?php


 //echo $_POST["first_name"];
 
 
 
 if (isset($_POST["selected_screen"]))
 {
  
  if ($_POST["selected_screen"] == "Open Account Submit")
  {
   
  $my_file = "customer_accounts.csv";
  $handle = fopen($my_file, "a");
  $data = $_POST["user_name"].",".$_POST["password"]."\r\n";
  fwrite($handle, $data);
  fclose($handle); 
   
   
  echo "<script>var selected_screen = \"Open Account Submit\";</script>";
  }
  
  
  else if ($_POST["selected_screen"] == "Login Account Submit")
  {
      
   
  echo "<script>var selected_screen = \"Login Account Submit\";</script>";
  }
  
  
  else if ($_POST["selected_screen"] == "Logout Account Submit")
  {
      
   
  echo "<script>var selected_screen = \"Logout Account Submit\";</script>";
  }
  
  
 }
 else
 {
 echo "<script>var selected_screen = \"Home\";</script>";
 }
 
 
 

echo "<script>


document.addEventListener(\"DOMContentLoaded\", function(event) {
   // alert(\"DOM fully loaded and parsed\");
  }); 
 
 
 function create_menu_button(text, left, top, width, height)
 {
  
  var button = document.createElement(\"button\");
  
  button.setAttribute(\"style\",
   \"background-color: grey; position: absolute; left: \" + left + \"px; top: \" + top + \"px; width: \" + width + \"px; height: \" + height + \"px; \" +
   \"border-style: none; color: white; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0; \");
   
   
   
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(text);   
  button.appendChild(textNode);
  
  
  
  
  button.addEventListener(\"mouseover\", mouseOver);
  button.addEventListener(\"mouseout\", mouseOut);
  button.addEventListener(\"mousedown\", mouseDown);
  
  function mouseOver() {
  button.setAttribute(\"style\",
   \"background-color: blue; position: absolute; left: \" + left + \"px; top: \" + top + \"px; width: \" + width + \"px; height: \" + height + \"px; \" +
   \"border-style: none; color: white; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0; \");
  }
  
  function mouseOut() {
  button.setAttribute(\"style\",
   \"background-color: grey; position: absolute; left: \" + left + \"px; top: \" + top + \"px; width: \" + width + \"px; height: \" + height + \"px; \" +
   \"border-style: none; color: white; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0; \");
  }
  
  function mouseDown() {
   
   selected_screen = text;
   
   create_screen();
    
   
  }
    
  document.body.appendChild(button);
  
  
  
 }
 
 
 function create_link_button(id, text, left, top, width, height)
 {
  
  var button = document.createElement(\"button\");
  
  button.setAttribute(\"style\",
   \"background-color: grey; position: absolute; left: \" + left + \"px; top: \" + top + \"px; width: \" + width + \"px; height: \" + height + \"px; \" +
   \"border-style: none; color: white; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0; \");
   
   
  var u = document.createElement(\"u\");     
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(text);   
  u.appendChild(textNode);
  button.appendChild(u);
  
  
  
  
  button.addEventListener(\"mouseover\", mouseOver);
  button.addEventListener(\"mouseout\", mouseOut);
  button.addEventListener(\"mousedown\", mouseDown);
  
  function mouseOver() {
  button.setAttribute(\"style\",
   \"background-color: grey; position: absolute; left: \" + left + \"px; top: \" + top + \"px; width: \" + width + \"px; height: \" + height + \"px; \" +
   \"border-style: none; color: blue; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0; \");
  }
  
  function mouseOut() {
  button.setAttribute(\"style\",
   \"background-color: grey; position: absolute; left: \" + left + \"px; top: \" + top + \"px; width: \" + width + \"px; height: \" + height + \"px; \" +
   \"border-style: none; color: white; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0; \");
  }
  
  function mouseDown() {
   
   
   selected_screen = id;
   
   create_screen();
    
    
   
  }
    
    
  return button;
  
  
  
 }
 
 
 function create_submit_button(id, text, left, top, width, height)
 {
  
  var button = document.createElement(\"input\");
  
  button.setAttribute(\"style\",
   \"background-color: grey; position: absolute; left: \" + left + \"px; top: \" + top + \"px; width: \" + width + \"px; height: \" + height + \"px; \" +
   \"border-style: none; color: white; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0; \");
   
    
  
  
  button.addEventListener(\"mouseover\", mouseOver);
  button.addEventListener(\"mouseout\", mouseOut);
  
  function mouseOver() {
  button.setAttribute(\"style\",
   \"background-color: grey; position: absolute; left: \" + left + \"px; top: \" + top + \"px; width: \" + width + \"px; height: \" + height + \"px; \" +
   \"border-style: none; color: blue; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0; text-decoration:underline; \");
  }
  
  function mouseOut() {
  button.setAttribute(\"style\",
   \"background-color: grey; position: absolute; left: \" + left + \"px; top: \" + top + \"px; width: \" + width + \"px; height: \" + height + \"px; \" +
   \"border-style: none; color: white; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0; text-decoration:underline; \");
  }
  
  
    
  button.type = \"submit\";
  button.value = text;
  button.style.textDecoration = \"underline\";
  
  
    
  return button;
  
  
  
 }
 
 function create_screen()
 {
  
  
  
  if (document.getElementById(\"header\") != null) document.getElementById(\"header\").remove();
  if (document.getElementById(\"main\") != null) document.getElementById(\"main\").remove();
  
  
  
  
  if (selected_screen == \"Home\")
  {
   var div = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div.id = \"header\";
   div.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div.style.left = \"100px\";
   div.style.top = \"90px\";
   div.style.fontSize = \"12px\";
   div.innerHTML = \"Home\";
   
   document.body.appendChild(div);
   
   var div = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div.id = \"main\";
   div.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div.style.left = \"100px\";
   div.style.top = \"125px\";
   div.style.width = \"700px\";
   div.style.height = \"400px\";
   div.style.background = \"grey\";   
   document.body.appendChild(div);
   
   
   var div2 = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div2.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div2.style.left = \"100px\";
   div2.style.top = \"125px\";
   div2.style.fontSize = \"12px\";
   div2.innerHTML = \"Welcome to Trading Charts\";   
   div.appendChild(div2);
   
   
  }
  else if (selected_screen == \"Account Management\")
  {
   var div = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div.id = \"header\";
   div.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div.style.left = \"100px\";
   div.style.top = \"90px\";
   div.style.fontSize = \"12px\";
   div.innerHTML = \"Account Management\";
   
   document.body.appendChild(div);
   
   var div = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div.id = \"main\";
   div.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div.style.left = \"100px\";
   div.style.top = \"125px\";
   div.style.width = \"700px\";
   div.style.height = \"400px\";
   div.style.background = \"grey\";   
   document.body.appendChild(div);
   
   
   
   var button = create_link_button(\"Open Account\", \"Open Account\", 100, 100, 100, 20);
   div.appendChild(button);
   
   var button = create_link_button(\"Login Account\", \"Login Account\", 100, 150, 100, 20);
   div.appendChild(button);
   
   
  }
  else if (selected_screen == \"Open Account\")
  {
   var form = document.createElement(\"form\");
   
   form.method = \"post\";
   
   
   var div = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div.id = \"header\";
   div.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div.style.left = \"100px\";
   div.style.top = \"90px\";
   div.style.fontSize = \"12px\";
   div.innerHTML = \"Open Account\";
   
   form.appendChild(div);
   
   var div = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div.id = \"main\";
   div.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div.style.left = \"100px\";
   div.style.top = \"125px\";
   div.style.width = \"700px\";
   div.style.height = \"400px\";
   div.style.background = \"grey\";   
   form.appendChild(div);
   
   
   var width = 500;
   var height = 35;
   var top = 20;
   
   
   var div2 = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div2.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div2.style.left = \"100px\";
   div2.style.top = top + \"px\";
   div.style.fontSize = \"12px\";
   div2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(\"Please enter the following information:\"));
   div.appendChild(div2);
   
   
   
   
   var hidden_input = document.createElement(\"input\");
   hidden_input.name = \"selected_screen\";
   hidden_input.type = \"hidden\";
   hidden_input.value = \"Open Account Submit\";
   div.appendChild(hidden_input);
     
   
   
   function create_field(id, name, left1, top1, width1, left2, top2, width2)
   {
    var div2_header = document.createElement(\"div\");
    div2_header.style.position = \"absolute\";
    div2_header.style.left = left1 + \"px\";
    div2_header.style.top = top1 + \"px\";
    div2_header.style.width = width1 + \"px\";
    div2_header.style.fontSize = \"12px\";
    div2_header.innerHTML = name;
    div2_header.style.background = \"grey\";
    div.appendChild(div2_header);

    
    var div2_input = document.createElement(\"input\");
    div2_input.style.position = \"absolute\";
    div2_input.style.left = left2 + \"px\";
    div2_input.style.top = top2 + \"px\";  
    div2_input.style.width = width2 + \"px\";  
    div2_input.style.height = 15 + \"px\";
    div2_input.name = id;
    div2_input.type = \"text\";
    div.appendChild(div2_input);
   }
   
   
   
   var left1 = 100;
   var width1 = 100;
   var left2 = 220;
   var width2 = 200;
   
   
   top += height; 
   create_field(\"user_name\", \"User Name\", left1, top, width1, left2, top - 3, width2);
   
   top += height;
   create_field(\"password\", \"Password\", left1, top, width1, left2, top - 3, width2);
   
   top += height;
   create_field(\"confirm_password\", \"Confirm Password\", left1, top, width1, left2, top - 3, width2);
      
   top += height;  
   create_field(\"first_name\", \"First Name\", left1, top, width1, left2, top - 3, width2);
   
   top += height;  
   create_field(\"last_name\", \"Last Name\", left1, top, width1, left2, top - 3, width2);
   
   top += height;
   create_field(\"country\", \"Country\", left1, top, width1, left2, top - 3, width2);
   
   top += height;
   create_field(\"phone\", \"Phone\", left1, top, width1, left2, top - 3, width2);
   
   top += height;
   create_field(\"email\", \"Email\", left1, top, width1, left2, top - 3, width2);
   
   
      
   top = 350;
   
   var button = create_submit_button(\"Open Account Submit\", \"Submit\", 100, top, 50, 20);
   div.appendChild(button);
   
   var button = create_link_button(\"Open Account Cancel\", \"Cancel\", 200, top, 50, 20);
   div.appendChild(button);
   
   document.body.appendChild(form);
   
   
  }
  else if (selected_screen == \"Login Account\")
  {
   var form = document.createElement(\"form\");
   
   form.method = \"post\";
   
   
   var div = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div.id = \"header\";
   div.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div.style.left = \"100px\";
   div.style.top = \"90px\";
   div.style.fontSize = \"12px\";
   div.innerHTML = \"Login Account\";
   
   form.appendChild(div);
   
   var div = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div.id = \"main\";
   div.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div.style.left = \"100px\";
   div.style.top = \"125px\";
   div.style.width = \"700px\";
   div.style.height = \"400px\";
   div.style.background = \"grey\";   
   form.appendChild(div);
   
   
   
   
   var hidden_input = document.createElement(\"input\");
   hidden_input.name = \"selected_screen\";
   hidden_input.type = \"hidden\";
   hidden_input.value = \"Login Account Submit\";
   div.appendChild(hidden_input);
   
   
   var width = 500;
   var height = 35;
   var top = 120; 
   
   
   var div2 = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div2.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div2.style.left = \"100px\";
   div2.style.top = top + \"px\";
   div.style.fontSize = \"12px\";
   div2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(\"Please enter your credentials:\"));
   div.appendChild(div2);
   
   
   
   
   var hidden_input = document.createElement(\"input\");
   hidden_input.name = \"selected_screen\";
   hidden_input.type = \"hidden\";
   hidden_input.value = \"Login Account Submit\";
   div.appendChild(hidden_input);
   
   
   
   function create_field(id, name, left1, top1, width1, left2, top2, width2)
   {
    var div2_header = document.createElement(\"div\");
    div2_header.style.position = \"absolute\";
    div2_header.style.left = left1 + \"px\";
    div2_header.style.top = top1 + \"px\";
    div2_header.style.width = width1 + \"px\";
    div2_header.style.fontSize = \"12px\";
    div2_header.innerHTML = name;
    div2_header.style.background = \"grey\";
    div.appendChild(div2_header);

    
    var div2_input = document.createElement(\"input\");
    div2_input.style.position = \"absolute\";
    div2_input.style.left = left2 + \"px\";
    div2_input.style.top = top2 + \"px\";  
    div2_input.style.width = width2 + \"px\";  
    div2_input.style.height = 15 + \"px\";
    div2_input.name = id;
    div2_input.type = \"text\";
    div.appendChild(div2_input);
   }
   
   
   var left1 = 100;
   var width1 = 100;
   var left2 = 230;
   var width2 = 200;
   
   top += height;   
   create_field(\"user_name\", \"User Name\", left1, top, width1, left2, top - 3, width2);
   
   top += height;
   create_field(\"password\", \"Password\", left1, top, width1, left2, top - 3, width2);
   
   
   
   top = 250;
   
   
   var button = create_submit_button(\"Open Account Submit\", \"Submit\", 100, top, 50, 20);
   div.appendChild(button);
   
   var button = create_link_button(\"Login Account Cancel\", \"Cancel\", 200, top, 50, 20);
   div.appendChild(button);
   
   document.body.appendChild(form);
   
   
  }
  else if (selected_screen == \"Open Account Submit\")
  {
   var div = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div.id = \"header\";
   div.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div.style.left = \"100px\";
   div.style.top = \"90px\";
   div.style.fontSize = \"12px\";
   div.innerHTML = \"Open Account\";
   
   document.body.appendChild(div);
   
   var div = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div.id = \"main\";
   div.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div.style.left = \"100px\";
   div.style.top = \"125px\";
   div.style.width = \"700px\";
   div.style.height = \"400px\";
   div.style.background = \"grey\";   
   document.body.appendChild(div);
   
   
   var div2 = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div2.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div2.style.left = \"100px\";
   div2.style.top = \"80px\";
   div2.style.fontSize = \"12px\";
   div2.innerHTML = \"Your Account is Being Processed.  You will be notified when it is ready.\";   
   div.appendChild(div2);
   
   
  }
  else if (selected_screen == \"Open Account Cancel\")
  {
   var div = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div.id = \"header\";
   div.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div.style.left = \"100px\";
   div.style.top = \"90px\";
   div.style.fontSize = \"12px\";
   div.innerHTML = \"Open Account\";
   
   document.body.appendChild(div);
   
   var div = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div.id = \"main\";
   div.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div.style.left = \"100px\";
   div.style.top = \"125px\";
   div.style.width = \"700px\";
   div.style.height = \"400px\";
   div.style.background = \"grey\";   
   document.body.appendChild(div);
   
   
   var div2 = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div2.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div2.style.left = \"100px\";
   div2.style.top = \"80px\";
   div2.style.fontSize = \"12px\";
   div2.innerHTML = \"Open Account is Canceled.\";   
   div.appendChild(div2);
   
   
  }
  else if (selected_screen == \"Login Account Submit\")
  {
   
   var form = document.createElement(\"form\");
   
   form.method = \"post\";
   
   
   var div = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div.id = \"header\";
   div.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div.style.left = \"100px\";
   div.style.top = \"90px\";
   div.style.fontSize = \"12px\";
   div.innerHTML = \"Main Account.\";
   
   form.appendChild(div);
   
   var div = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div.id = \"main\";
   div.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div.style.left = \"100px\";
   div.style.top = \"125px\";
   div.style.width = \"700px\";
   div.style.height = \"400px\";
   div.style.background = \"grey\";   
   form.appendChild(div);
   
   
   
   
   
   var hidden_input = document.createElement(\"input\");
   hidden_input.name = \"selected_screen\";
   hidden_input.type = \"hidden\";
   hidden_input.value = \"Logout Account Submit\";
   div.appendChild(hidden_input);
   
   
   
   var div2 = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div2.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div2.style.left = \"100px\";
   div2.style.top = \"80px\";
   div2.style.fontSize = \"12px\";
   div2.innerHTML = \"You are logged into your account.\";   
   div.appendChild(div2);
   
   
   var button = create_submit_button(\"Logout\", \"Logout\", 100, 250, 50, 20);
   div.appendChild(button);
   
   
   
   document.body.appendChild(form);
   
   
  }
  else if (selected_screen == \"Login Account Cancel\")
  {
   var div = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div.id = \"header\";
   div.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div.style.left = \"100px\";
   div.style.top = \"90px\";
   div.style.fontSize = \"12px\";
   div.innerHTML = \"Login Account\";
   
   document.body.appendChild(div);
   
   var div = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div.id = \"main\";
   div.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div.style.left = \"100px\";
   div.style.top = \"125px\";
   div.style.width = \"700px\";
   div.style.height = \"400px\";
   div.style.background = \"grey\";   
   document.body.appendChild(div);
   
   
   var div2 = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div2.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div2.style.left = \"100px\";
   div2.style.top = \"80px\";
   div2.style.fontSize = \"12px\";
   div2.innerHTML = \"Login Account is Canceled.\";   
   div.appendChild(div2);
   
   
  }
  else if (selected_screen == \"Logout Account Submit\")
  {
   var div = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div.id = \"header\";
   div.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div.style.left = \"100px\";
   div.style.top = \"90px\";
   div.style.fontSize = \"12px\";
   div.innerHTML = \"Logout Account\";
   
   document.body.appendChild(div);
   
   var div = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div.id = \"main\";
   div.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div.style.left = \"100px\";
   div.style.top = \"125px\";
   div.style.width = \"700px\";
   div.style.height = \"400px\";
   div.style.background = \"grey\";   
   document.body.appendChild(div);
   
   
   var div2 = document.createElement(\"div\");
   div2.style.position = \"absolute\";
   div2.style.left = \"100px\";
   div2.style.top = \"80px\";
   div2.style.fontSize = \"12px\";
   div2.innerHTML = \"You are logged out.\";   
   div.appendChild(div2);
   
   
  }
  
  
  
  
  
 }
 
 
 
 var left = 100;
 var width = 150;
  
 create_menu_button(\"Home\", left, 50, width, 25);
 
 left += width + 10;
 create_menu_button(\"Account Management\", left, 50, width, 25);
 
 
 create_screen();

 
 
 
 </script>";
 
 
 

?>








</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Instead of having a massive amount of code in a string that you echo, just close the PHP block `?>`, write all the code and then open the block  again if you need to with `<?php`. That will make it _way_ easier to read, you'll get syntax highlighting and you don't need to care about escaping quotes.

Comment: I would also recommend putting the JS in a separate js-file. It will make it easier to maintain.

Comment: The question is also too broad. We know nothing about the server it's hosted on. There can be _many_ reasons why there's a delay. It can be a slow server, low on memory, slow CPU, many requests, bad network connection, many processes running on the server etc. It can literally be anything. You need to do some debugging and profiling to narrow the issue down.

Comment: the simple reaon could be, that the page has to fully load before you even start to put anything on screen. - _BUT_ I don't see a noticable, more than usual delay when visiting the site.

Comment: For a possible solution, is there a way to display the site's contents only when loading is complete?

Comment: that's what you already do

Answer (score 0):

```
Found a solution.  Using jquery solved the problem.  Essentially it allowed me to post variables to the server without actually submitting the variables by a regular form.  A snippet of the code is shown below.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<!-- https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp  -->

<!-- google -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- microsoft -->
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>




</head>
<body>


<?php


$name = $_POST['postname'];
$loaded = $_POST['postloaded'];


if ($name != null)

echo "your input is ".$name;



   

if ($loaded == null)
{
   

echo "<script>



document.addEventListener(\"DOMContentLoaded\", function(event) {
   
   
       
        var loaded = true;
       
        $.post('index.php', {postloaded:loaded},
       
       
        function(data)
        {
           
            $('#result').html(data);
           
        });
       
   
  });   
 
 


    var div = document.createElement(\"div\");
    div.setAttribute(\"id\", \"result\");
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    var form = document.createElement(\"form\");
   
    var input = document.createElement(\"input\");
    input.setAttribute(\"type\", \"text\");
    input.setAttribute(\"id\", \"name\");   
    form.appendChild(input);
   
    var br = document.createElement(\"br\");
    form.appendChild(br);
   
   
    var input = document.createElement(\"input\");
    input.setAttribute(\"type\", \"button\");
    input.setAttribute(\"value\", \"submit\");
    input.setAttribute(\"onclick\", \"post();\");
    form.appendChild(input);
       
   
    document.body.appendChild(form);
       
       
    function post()
    {
       
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var loaded = true;
       
        $.post('index.php', {postname:name, postloaded:loaded},
       
       
        function(data)
        {
           
            $('#result').html(data);
           
        });
       
       
       
       
    }
   
   


   
   
   
</script>";

}



?>



</body>
</html>
```